# How to shorten mysql join query to avoid manual typing of each row?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, pymysql

I have a table that gets new rows for eg. I'd add more than 100 features like phone_number, username to the processed_donors to this table very soon.IS it possible to simplify this json_object(****) so It's not an evergrowing list? Some way to use pandas+python, select * etc?

```sql
---        read_cur.execute("""

   select a.donor_id,
          json_object('city', a.city,
                      'name', a.name,
                      'zip', a.zip,
                      'state', a.state,
                      'address', a.address),
          b.donor_id,
          json_object('city', b.city,
                      'name', b.name,
                      'zip', b.zip,
                      'state', b.state,
                      'address', b.address)
   from (select DISTINCT l.donor_id as east, r.donor_id as west
         from blocking_map as l
         INNER JOIN blocking_map as r
         using (block_key)
         where l.donor_id < r.donor_id) ids
   INNER JOIN processed_donors a on ids.east=a.donor_id
   INNER JOIN processed_donors b on ids.west=b.donor_id

---               """)
```

Comment: *IS it possible to simplify this json_object(****) so It's not an evergrowing list?* You may add these additional attributes as one nested JSON object (or as a bunch of objects grouped logically), not as separate attributes objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this in two steps.

First, you need to get all the columns of the `processed_donors` table. Then you can use this result to build your query string.

```
read_cur.execute('DESCRIBE processed_donors')
describe_result = read_cur.fetchall()
column_names = [row[0] for row in describe_result]
# column_names should be ['city', 'name', 'zip', 'state']

pairs = [f"'{col}', a.{col}" for col in column_names]
jo_a = f'json_object({", ".join(pairs)})'
# jo_a is json_object('city', a.city, 'name', a.name, 'zip', a.zip, 'state', a.state)
```

Note that I don't have a mysql DB running here, so I can't check if that's the correct way how to build the `column_names`, but I hope you get the idea. You can use the same process to build the `json_object` for `b` and then build a query string.

Please keep in mind that normally, creating a SQL query manually like this is a bad idea do to SQL injection vulnerabilities, but I presume there's no user input involved here and you control the names of the columns, so it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Milan, This is slightly segwayed. In the future, I want to concatenate that json_object with inputs from another table "time_data" so that jo_a would have time data in it. How would I be able to accommodate that?

Comment: In a similar manner, first get all the columns you need (DESCRIBE time_data), build the column_names list and then you should be able to build the query string.

Comment: would I have to change the inner join to pull that data?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your tables but seems like it, yes, because you're pulling data from another table. It has to be joined in.